# Content Security Policy: resource blocked but CSP is configured to allow it

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-analytics, greasemonkey, content-security-policy

I have a GreaseMonkey user script that injects some HTML code into a page, and the HTML code is containing some JavaScript which points to an external script, which requires Google Analytics to work.
To "bypass" Content Security Policy i injected this code just before :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; 
script-src www.google-analytics.com * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src * 'unsafe-inline'; 
img-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; ">
```

But it drops the following error in console:

```
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at 
https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js (“script-src”).
```

I allowed everything in CSP, but it still doesn't work.
(If needed, this is my userscript code)

```
$("head").append("<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Security-Policy\" content=\"default-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; script-src www.google-analytics.com * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src * 'unsafe-inline'; img-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; \">");
$("body").append ( `
    <div id="AHHAHAHAHAH">
<script src="https://examp.le/thisScriptUsesGoogleAnalytics.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>    </div>
` );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear what you want to achieve. It does not make any sense to change the `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="...">` tag script based in the DOM. Just don't set it in the first place or set it according to your needs.

Comment: My needs are to allow everything, and since I want to inject it to sites that I don't own, and i think that the site i want to inject it to ( duckduckgo.com ) sets CSP into the http header _(Because if I don't add the `content security policy` meta, i get this error too)_, I need to replace it so I can inject the script.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the CSP entirely. You can't inject stuff in pages you don't own, that's the point of it.